# Automatically place text from two data variables into an svg with d3

Tags: data-binding, text, svg, d3.js

I am learning D3, and I want to learn how to add text to an svg in different locations following a formula rather than adding each text element to a location manually. Adding the letters A, B, C works below, but then the first three numbers are hidden because the first three text elements are already occupied by A, B, C.

What can I change to be able to place my letters and numbers separately? Thanks for your advice.

```
        var w = 600;
        var h = 500;

        var letters = ["A","B","C"];
        var numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5"];

        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height",h);

        svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(letters)
                .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i+1)*100})
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {return (i+1)*100}) 
            .style("text.anchor", "left")
            .style("font-size", "40px")
            .style("fill", "gray")
            .attr("font-family","monospace")
            .text(function(d){return d});

        svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(numbers)
                .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i+1)*100})
            .attr("y", 40) 
            .style("text.anchor", "left")
            .style("font-size", "40px")
            .style("fill", "gray")
            .attr("font-family","monospace")
            .text(function(d){return d});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make the `text` elements for the `numbers` and `letters` different. One easy way to do that is using classes.

```js
svg.selectAll('text.letter')
   .date(letters)
  .enter()
   .append('text')
   .classed('letter', true)
   // ...

svg.selectAll('text.number')
   .date(numbers)
  .enter()
   .append('text')
   .classed('number', true)
   // ...
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YVL8S/)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Simply changing text elements fixed my problem. I'll try using the .classed... as well if I run into further problems.